# Создание функции для определения скидки

Tags: sql-server, функции

Необходимо написать функцию, которая в зависимости от стоимости покупки определяет скидку.
Не представляю, как это можно сделать на T-SQL. :(

```
10000> 2%
40000> 3%
100000> 5%
```

На вход поступает FLOAT - стоимость покупки, на выходе FLOAT - скидка поделенная на 100.

Comment: @T2skler, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Будет иметь общий вид:

```
<pre>
@переменная со стоимостью покупки
CREATE PROC имя
@скидка float
AS
IF @переменная со стоимостью покупки > n
BEGIN
делаем какой-то запрос, или выводите куда вам нужно данные
END
</pre>
```